# save specific array from multi-array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an called $array as follows.  I need to be able to pull out specific arrays within it based off the [day] value.

So for instance, I could have $day2 equal to $array[1] because its day value is 2 and so on.  How can I go about doing that?  They are not ordered when they come in and there cannot be multiples as in the max amount of arrays in $array can be 7 as there are 7 days in the week.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 4
            [day] => 1
            [12a] => 0
            [1a] => 0
            [2a] => 0
            [3a] => 0
            [4a] => 0
            [5a] => 0
            [6a] => 0
            [7a] => 0
            [8a] => 0
            [9a] => 0
            [10a] => 0
            [11a] => 0
            [12p] => 1
            [1p] => 1
            [2p] => 1
            [3p] => 1
            [4p] => 1
            [5p] => 1
            [6p] => 1
            [7p] => 1
            [8p] => 0
            [9p] => 0
            [10p] => 0
            [11p] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 4
            [day] => 2
            [12a] => 1
            [1a] => 1
            [2a] => 1
            [3a] => 1
            [4a] => 1
            [5a] => 1
            [6a] => 1
            [7a] => 1
            [8a] => 1
            [9a] => 1
            [10a] => 1
            [11a] => 1
            [12p] => 1
            [1p] => 1
            [2p] => 1
            [3p] => 1
            [4p] => 1
            [5p] => 1
            [6p] => 1
            [7p] => 1
            [8p] => 1
            [9p] => 0
            [10p] => 1
            [11p] => 1
        )

)
```

**EDIT for anyone interested :**

Here is what I ended up with... $settings being the original multi array...

```
//set counter
$counter = 0;

//loop through and set different day arrays
foreach($settings as $value) {
    // inc counter
    $counter++;

    //set array using variable variables ($hourstemp is actually $hours1, $hours2, $hours3, etc.)
    if($value['day'] == $counter) {
        $hourstemp = 'hours'.$counter;
        $$hourstemp = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still dont quite understand what you are looking to do. You want to assign `$array[1]` to a new variable called `$day2` because `$array[1]['day'] == 2`? So you want to have 7 new variables, `$day1`, `$day2`, `$day3`, `$day4`, `$day5`, `$day6`, `$day7` All matching on the $array[X]['day']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a specific day:

```
$day = 2;

foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value['day'] == $day) {
         $result = $value;
         break;
    }
}
```

Or if they are consistent in that 'day' is always 1 greater than the index, then just:

```
$result = $array[$day-1];
```

Or if you want to reorder the array so the index is the 'day':

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $result[$value['day']] = $value;
}
//then you can just use $result[$day]
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way without foreach, but I could not find anything... this is working as expected.